# A word which means that the existence of one thing does not mean another thing cannot also exist

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice

For Example,

Solution A already exists, however it is a poor solution. We created solution B. The existence of B however, does not _____ the existence of A.

I was thinking preclude, however I thought that given that A already exists, this wouldn't fit. Thoughts?

Edit:

To be clear, what I mean is that both are allowed to exist at the same time. ie. The existence of B doesn't mean A can't exist and be used.

I thought I might be able to use: *The existence of B does not preclude the existence of A.*

However, I'm unsure if this is correct.

Comment: Invalidate? Disprove? Not sure what you are seeking.

Comment: I think the word you seek IS ***preclude***.

Comment: A bit too existential for me. And creationist. It’s not clear what you are trying to say. Is this a mathematical solution and you are saying both are correct? Are you saying that you have found a better way of doing something (counting heads rather than counting legs and dividing by two) but both will work? I think that if you formulate your question in simple terms you will be able to answer it yourself.

Comment: Hi Tyler, welcome to EL&U.  You could say, 'The existence of B however, does not ***rely on*** the existence of A.

Comment: disavow, negate, exclude

Comment: @FumbleFingers You should post an answer, because you're right.

Comment: @Spencer: ***preclude*** is a 50-cent word. Perhaps in OP's context (especially if he's a *learner*) it might be better to use a 10-cent alternative such as ***rule out***. But it looks like a POB question to me anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Negate](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/negating):

> - to deny the existence, evidence, or truth of: *an investigation tending to negate any supernatural influences.*
> - to nullify or cause to be ineffective: *Progress on the study has been negated by the lack of funds.*

So, "The existence of B however, does not negate the existence of A."

Answer (score 0):

In the sentence you offered,
"invalidate"
jumps out as a possible choice.However,
'preclude'
is also an excellent choice.

The reasons one might choose one word over another are as follows:

Preclude comes from the Latin praecludere, praeclusum;
where prae means 'before' + claudere means 'to shut'.
which implies a temporal aspect to the data. With preclude, you are stopping something ahead of time.

Invalidate is derived from
'in' (the negation of) + valid
and valid comes from
the Frech invalide, which comes from the
Latin invalidus = infirm or weak

Therefore, invalidate means:

1. Of no force, weight, or cogency; not valid; weak.

The word roots and definitions come from The Collaborative International Dictionary of English v.0.48
I hope this helps.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).